# How to successfully implement "Auto-accept requests?"

Tags: 2010, permissions, auto-approve

> Caution: If you select yes for the Auto-accept requests option, any user requesting access to this group will automatically be added as a member of the group and receive the permission levels associated with the group.

I am attempting to get *exactly* the functionality described in this warning in a SharePoint site (it is a sub-site of another site) which does **not** inherit permissions from the larger site.

I have no idea what I need to change to get this to work as intended. This is the only permission group which has "Allow requests to join" selected, the only group which has "Auto-Accept requests" selected, the group is the default group for the site, but in spite of this I get email requests.

- What do I need to do to actually get "auto accept requests" to work for a group for a SharePoint site?

Answer (score 5):

The auto-access requests does work, but it's a little less-than-intuitive IMHO.  The 'Request Access' option that users see (if enabled) when navigating to a site that they do not have access to, is NOT related to this functionality.  It's a separate site request action and will simply send an email notification to the recipient of your choice.  The auto-access capability is contained within the settings of a group, and users must request to join the relevant group for the functionality to work.

1. Navigate to the relevant group membership page: https://sharepointrootsite.com/_layouts/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=XXXX
2. Click the 'Actions' dropdown and select 'Join Group'

Users will then be presented with a message welcoming them to the group, and will now have any associated access privileges.  I'm assuming that if users don't have read access to the root site collection housing the group membership page, then they will not be able to join the group but I haven't tested this theory.

Thanks!

Comment: Although the question wasn't formulated, I believe that this is *the* answer.

Comment: It works, but how do you get the GroupID if you're not an admin?

Comment: Manual link for "Join here!" and instructions which navigates to the url above?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the user must have read-only access to the sharepoint in order to get the actions button that enables them to join the group and be auto-accepted to the group.