# Auto-accepting users

Tags: permissions, access, approval

I'm looking for a way to auto-accept people when they get the screen saying they require permission to access this site and submit an access request.

I am aware the standard auto-accept feature doesn't do quite this and found information about it here:

[How to successfully implement "Auto-accept requests?"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66210/how-to-successfully-implement-auto-accept-requests)

The site isn't visible publicly so people can't request to join as above, but it would be really useful to be able to auto-approve requests that come from one of the request permission pages. Has anyone found a workaround to this?

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When SP User requests access to a Site and you allow it, he/she is added to Site Members Group.

What you can do, just to add Everyone to that Group :)

STEPS:

1. Site Settings
2. People and Groups
3. YOURSITENAME Members
4. New
5. Add Users
6. Everyone